# Looping over 5D masked Numpy array Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am a beginner in Python and I faced a problem in maintaining the same size of the last 2 dimensions in the 5D array that I have while looping over it to do some calculations, as they represent the latitude and longitude of the map that I will plot as result from this calculation. The calculation that I want to apply is in a function called (line), as I call this function inside the loop to do the calculation on the (wind_data) 5D array. But I have an error (`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`)

```
import numpy as np

Swept_Area=5026  
Air_Density= 1.225 


def line(v):
    prob=np.empty(shape=v.shape)
    idx_low=np.where(v<=4)
    idx_mid=np.where((v >= 4) & (v <= 15))
    idx_mid2=np.where((v > 15) & (v <= 25))
    idx_high=np.where(v>25)
    
    m=  0.5 * Swept_Area * Air_Density *0.29 *  v**3   * 10**-3 
    prob[idx_low]=0
    prob[idx_mid]=m[(v >= 4) & (v <= 15)] 
    prob[idx_mid2]=3000
    prob[idx_high]=0

    return prob

prob=np.empty(shape=(wind_data.shape[3],wind_data.shape[4]))

for lat_index in range(wind_data.shape[3]):
   for long_index in range(wind_data.shape[4]):
        prob[lat_index,long_index]=line(wind_data[:,:,:,lat_index,long_index])
```

Comment: Is numpy the only module that you're importing?  Please include the import statements needed to run your code snippet.

Comment: sorry, yes numpy is the only package that i am using for this code, I just updated the question.

Comment: or if the result can be in the size of the last three indexes in the 5D array it will be easier to be to handle it.